# Kotlin higherorder function (callable references) compiler crash

Tags: kotlin

so Im messing around with Kotlin for some Android development and ran into a compiler bug... would be great if someone had some input.

the Kotlin example for callable references (passing functions via arguments in this case) is crashing my environment. for me this is absolutely a critical feature of the language, and not having it work cripples me...

my environment is:
Android Studio 0.3.6
Kotlin plugin 0.6.602

any insight would be much appreciated

```
fun isOdd(x: Int) = x % 2 != 0

val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
println(numbers.filter(::isOdd))
```

and the compiler error is:

```
<no path>:1:org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Cannot resolve: callableReferenceFakeCall
File being compiled and position: (1,9) in dummy.kt
PsiElement: callableReferenceFakeCall(p0)

    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1893)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetCallExpression.accept(JetCallExpression.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:257)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:273)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:277)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2122)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeFunction(ExpressionCodegen.java:2014)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen$4.doGenerateBody(ExpressionCodegen.java:2531)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:290)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:143)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ClosureCodegen.gen(ClosureCodegen.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallableReferenceExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:2597)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallableReferenceExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetCallableReferenceExpression.accept(JetCallableReferenceExpression.java:57)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:257)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:273)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:277)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.pushMethodArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2336)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.pushArgumentsAndInvoke(ExpressionCodegen.java:2138)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2134)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeFunction(ExpressionCodegen.java:2014)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1922)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetCallExpression.accept(JetCallExpression.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:257)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitDotQualifiedExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:2605)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitDotQualifiedExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetDotQualifiedExpression.accept(JetDotQualifiedExpression.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:257)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:273)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:277)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.pushMethodArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2336)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.pushArgumentsAndInvoke(ExpressionCodegen.java:2138)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2134)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeFunction(ExpressionCodegen.java:2014)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1922)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetCallExpression.accept(JetCallExpression.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitJetElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitJetElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitExpression(JetVisitor.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetVisitor.visitCallExpression(JetVisitor.java:246)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetCallExpression.accept(JetCallExpression.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:257)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1429)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1288)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.lang.psi.JetBlockExpression.accept(JetBlockExpression.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:257)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:273)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1590)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:290)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:143)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.MemberCodegen.genFunctionOrProperty(MemberCodegen.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ImplementationBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ImplementationBodyCodegen.java:1594)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateClassBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generate(ClassBodyCodegen.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.NamespaceCodegen.generateClassOrObject(NamespaceCodegen.java:206)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.NamespaceCodegen.generate(NamespaceCodegen.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.NamespaceCodegen.generate(NamespaceCodegen.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.generateNamespace(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:298)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyzeAndGenerate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:260)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileBunchOfSources(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.java:187)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.java:142)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.compile(Tasks.kt:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:527)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:283)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:108)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

        ^
:gf_publisher:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
```

Comment: See my answer below. Note that users are highly encouraged to report compiler bugs to the issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/KT. This particular issues has already been reported: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3704

Comment: The issue KT-3704 has been resolved and is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a bug related to local functions (functions declared inside functions). 
As a workaround, use this code:

```
fun isOdd(x: Int) = x % 2 != 0

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    println(numbers.filter(::isOdd))
}
```

The important part is that `isOdd()` is defined outside any function.

Comment: thanks Andrey. It would be amazing if this got fixed soon, since it enables to a large extend a functional style of coding in Kotlin. By the way, great work on the language... I actually enjoy JVM coding now... keep it up :)

Comment: @deepblue the issue no longer exists, is an old resolved bug.